# Loop each Items in c# using XElement

Tags: c#, linq, xmldocument, xdoc

I am facing some difficulty in swapping the `id` attribute in the list of `Item`s in a C# `XDocument`. The `id` is a reference.

Input:

```
<Items>
    <Item base="book_bookref1_ref1">
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <Ref>bookref1</Ref>
    </Item>
    <Item base="book_bookref1_ref2">
        <Name>Test2</Name>
        <Ref>bookref1</Ref>
    </Item>
    <Item base="book_bookref2_ref1">
        <Name>Test3</Name>
        <Ref>bookref2</Ref>
    </Item>
    <Item base="book_bookref2_ref2">
        <Name>Test4</Name>
        <Ref>bookref2</Ref>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

Expected Output:

```
<Items>
    <Item base="book_bookref1_ref1" id="book_bookref1_ref2">
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <Ref>bookref1</Ref>
    </Item>
    <Item base="book_bookref1_ref2" id="book_bookref1_ref1">
        <Name>Test2</Name>
        <Ref>bookref1</Ref>
    </Item>
    <Item base="book_bookref2_ref1" id="book_bookref2_ref2">
        <Name>Test3</Name>
        <Ref>bookref2</Ref>
    </Item>
    <Item base="book_bookref2_ref2" id="bookref2_ref1">
        <Name>Test4</Name>
        <Ref>bookref2</Ref>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

There is a tag `<Ref>` where one part of value `ex:bookref1` is a reference for **Base** attribute `book_bookref1_ref1` for the **1st and 2nd** `Item`.

I need to write the 2nd 'id' to the 1st `Item` and write the 1st `id` to the 2nd `Item` in the loop. Similarly for the 3rd and 4th `Item`. There can be many but it's like a combination (1 & 2, 3 & 4, 5 & 6, etc).

The problem here is there can be multiple `Item`s and there is no relation in the `Item` to map the `Id` attribute.

The code I'm using is loading `XMLDocument` into `XDocument` getting the `Item`s in LINQ.

```
Var doc = XDocument.Load(xml) 
var ItemsList 
foreach(var itm in ItemsList)
{
    // I'm stuck here. How do we get the id attribute value based on Ref tag?
}
```

Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in XML is impossible with a little LINQ (and [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/), in this example):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(input);
foreach(var pair in xdoc.XPathSelectElements("Items/Item").Batch(2).ToArray())
{
    pair[0].SetAttributeValue(XName.Get("id"), pair[1].Attribute(XName.Get("base")).Value);
    pair[1].SetAttributeValue(XName.Get("id"), pair[0].Attribute(XName.Get("base")).Value);
}
```

This enumerates not each `Item`, not each `Item` pair (two elements in a batch). You only need to tweak this to decide what to do if an odd element remains at the end of the loop.

MoreLinq is for `.Batch()` extension method, but if you need, you can easily write it yourself.